# Parsing XML with PHP for Wordpress Product List

Tags: php, xml, parsing, object

I am trying to parse an XML file with PHP so that I can replace a certain tag's value.

This is what the relevant XML looks like:

```
<channel>
    <item>
        <title>Woo Logo</title>
        <link>http://demo2.woothemes.com/woocommerce/product/woo-logo/</link>
        <pubDate>Fri, 07 Jun 2013 10:35:51 +0000</pubDate>
        <dc:creator>wooteam</dc:creator>
        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://demo2.woothemes.com/dummydata/?post_type=product&#038;p=15</guid>
        <description></description>
        <content:encoded><![CDATA[Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.]]></content:encoded>
        <excerpt:encoded><![CDATA[Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.]]></excerpt:encoded>
        <wp:post_id>15</wp:post_id>
        <wp:post_date>2013-06-07 10:35:51</wp:post_date>
        <wp:post_date_gmt>2013-06-07 10:35:51</wp:post_date_gmt>
        <wp:comment_status>open</wp:comment_status>
        <wp:ping_status>closed</wp:ping_status>
        <wp:post_name>woo-logo</wp:post_name>
        <wp:status>publish</wp:status>
        <wp:post_parent>0</wp:post_parent>
        <wp:menu_order>0</wp:menu_order>
        <wp:post_type>product</wp:post_type>
        <wp:post_password></wp:post_password>
        <wp:is_sticky>0</wp:is_sticky>
        <category domain="product_cat" nicename="clothing"><![CDATA[Clothing]]></category>
        <category domain="product_type" nicename="simple"><![CDATA[simple]]></category>
        <category domain="product_cat" nicename="t-shirts"><![CDATA[T-shirts]]></category>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_edit_last</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[3]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_thumbnail_id</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[16]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_visibility</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[visible]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_stock_status</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[instock]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>total_sales</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[0]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_downloadable</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[no]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_virtual</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[no]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_product_image_gallery</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[17]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_regular_price</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[20]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_sale_price</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[18]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_tax_status</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_tax_class</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_purchase_note</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_featured</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[no]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_weight</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_length</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_width</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_height</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_sku</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_product_attributes</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[a:0:{}]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_sale_price_dates_from</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_sale_price_dates_to</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_price</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[18]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_sold_individually</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_stock</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[5]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_backorders</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[no]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_manage_stock</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[yes]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_upsell_ids</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[a:1:{i:0;s:2:"60";}]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:comment>
            <wp:comment_id>13</wp:comment_id>
            <wp:comment_author><![CDATA[Cobus Bester]]></wp:comment_author>
            <wp:comment_author_email>bester.c@gmail.com</wp:comment_author_email>
            <wp:comment_author_url></wp:comment_author_url>
            <wp:comment_author_IP>196.215.9.147</wp:comment_author_IP>
            <wp:comment_date>2013-06-07 11:57:05</wp:comment_date>
            <wp:comment_date_gmt>2013-06-07 11:57:05</wp:comment_date_gmt>
            <wp:comment_content><![CDATA[Simple and effective design. One of my favorites.]]></wp:comment_content>
            <wp:comment_approved>1</wp:comment_approved>
            <wp:comment_type></wp:comment_type>
            <wp:comment_parent>0</wp:comment_parent>
            <wp:comment_user_id>0</wp:comment_user_id>
            <wp:commentmeta>
                <wp:meta_key>akismet_error</wp:meta_key>
                <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[1370606225]]></wp:meta_value>
            </wp:commentmeta>
            <wp:commentmeta>
                <wp:meta_key>akismet_history</wp:meta_key>
                <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[a:4:{s:4:"time";d:1370606225.6765859127044677734375;s:7:"message";s:92:"Akismet was unable to check this comment (response: ), will automatically retry again later.";s:5:"event";s:11:"check-error";s:4:"user";s:0:"";}]]></wp:meta_value>
            </wp:commentmeta>
            <wp:commentmeta>
                <wp:meta_key>akismet_as_submitted</wp:meta_key>
                <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[a:67:{s:15:"comment_post_ID";i:15;s:14:"comment_author";s:12:"Cobus Bester";s:20:"comment_author_email";s:18:"bester.c@gmail.com";s:18:"comment_author_url";N;s:15:"comment_content";s:49:"Simple and effective design. One of my favorites.";s:12:"comment_type";s:0:"";s:14:"comment_parent";i:0;s:7:"user_ID";i:0;s:7:"user_ip";s:13:"196.215.9.147";s:10:"user_agent";s:119:"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.65 Safari/537.31";s:8:"referrer";s:56:"http://demo2.woothemes.com/woocommerce/product/woo-logo/";s:4:"blog";s:38:"http://demo2.woothemes.com/woocommerce";s:9:"blog_lang";s:5:"en_US";s:12:"blog_charset";s:5:"UTF-8";s:9:"permalink";s:56:"http://demo2.woothemes.com/woocommerce/product/woo-logo/";s:21:"akismet_comment_nonce";s:6:"passed";s:11:"POST_author";s:12:"Cobus Bester";s:10:"POST_email";s:18:"bester.c@gmail.com";s:11:"POST_rating";s:1:"4";s:12:"POST_comment";s:49:"Simple and effective design. One of my favorites.";s:7:"POST__n";s:10:"a80bd2f042";s:21:"POST__wp_http_referer";s:30:"/woocommerce/product/woo-logo/";s:11:"POST_submit";s:13:"Submit Review";s:20:"POST_comment_post_ID";s:2:"15";s:19:"POST_comment_parent";s:1:"0";s:26:"POST_akismet_comment_nonce";s:10:"bbd941e9bf";s:15:"SERVER_SOFTWARE";s:6:"Apache";s:11:"REQUEST_URI";s:33:"/woocommerce/wp-comments-post.php";s:15:"REDIRECT_IS_WPE";s:1:"1";s:27:"REDIRECT_WPE_CAN_WRITE_DISK";s:1:"0";s:15:"REDIRECT_STATUS";s:3:"200";s:6:"IS_WPE";s:1:"1";s:18:"WPE_CAN_WRITE_DISK";s:1:"0";s:9:"HTTP_HOST";s:19:"demo2.woothemes.com";s:13:"HTTP_X_LB_KEY";s:8:"woodemo2";s:13:"HTTP_X_IS_BOT";s:1:"0";s:15:"HTTP_USER_AGENT";s:119:"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.65 Safari/537.31";s:15:"HTTP_CONNECTION";s:5:"close";s:14:"CONTENT_LENGTH";s:3:"273";s:18:"HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL";s:9:"max-age=0";s:11:"HTTP_ACCEPT";s:63:"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";s:11:"HTTP_ORIGIN";s:26:"http://demo2.woothemes.com";s:12:"CONTENT_TYPE";s:33:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded";s:12:"HTTP_REFERER";s:56:"http://demo2.woothemes.com/woocommerce/product/woo-logo/";s:20:"HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING";s:17:"gzip,deflate,sdch";s:20:"HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE";s:14:"en-US,en;q=0.8";s:19:"HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET";s:30:"ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3";s:11:"HTTP_COOKIE";s:0:"";s:4:"PATH";s:28:"/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin";s:16:"SERVER_SIGNATURE";s:0:"";s:11:"SERVER_NAME";s:19:"demo2.woothemes.com";s:11:"SERVER_ADDR";s:9:"127.0.0.1";s:11:"SERVER_PORT";s:2:"80";s:11:"REMOTE_ADDR";s:13:"196.215.9.147";s:13:"DOCUMENT_ROOT";s:26:"/nas/wp/www/sites/woodemo2";s:12:"SERVER_ADMIN";s:18:"[no address given]";s:15:"SCRIPT_FILENAME";s:47:"/nas/wp/www/sites/woodemo2/wp-comments-post.php";s:11:"REMOTE_PORT";s:5:"57596";s:12:"REDIRECT_URL";s:33:"/woocommerce/wp-comments-post.php";s:17:"GATEWAY_INTERFACE";s:7:"CGI/1.1";s:15:"SERVER_PROTOCOL";s:8:"HTTP/1.0";s:14:"REQUEST_METHOD";s:4:"POST";s:12:"QUERY_STRING";s:0:"";s:11:"SCRIPT_NAME";s:21:"/wp-comments-post.php";s:8:"PHP_SELF";s:21:"/wp-comments-post.php";s:12:"REQUEST_TIME";s:10:"1370606225";s:25:"comment_post_modified_gmt";s:19:"2013-06-07 11:15:25";}]]></wp:meta_value>
            </wp:commentmeta>
            <wp:commentmeta>
                <wp:meta_key>rating</wp:meta_key>
                <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[4]]></wp:meta_value>
            </wp:commentmeta>
            <wp:commentmeta>
                <wp:meta_key>akismet_history</wp:meta_key>
                <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[a:4:{s:4:"time";d:1370607940.89634990692138671875;s:7:"message";s:46:"wooteam changed the comment status to approved";s:5:"event";s:15:"status-approved";s:4:"user";s:7:"wooteam";}]]></wp:meta_value>
            </wp:commentmeta>
        </wp:comment>
    </item>
</channel>
```

I am interested in the `wp:postmeta` block that has to do with price - the one with `<wp:meta_key>_price</wp:meta_key>`. Here is what I have tried to do:

```
$dom=new DOMDocument();
$dom->load("/var/www/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/dummy-data/nspro.xml");

$root=$dom->documentElement;

$markers=$root->getElementsByTagName('item');

echo $markers->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('wp:postmeta')->item(22)->getElementsByTagName('wp:meta_key')->item(0)->textContent;
```

This doesn't work - I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object.
```

The error is referencing my call with that function right after `$markers->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('wp:postmeta')->item(22)->`. Apparently, I can't use it the same way I do when I reference the first `<item>` in the list. How do I go about accessing the tags inside of the `<wp:postmeta>` blocks?

Comment: Why not [`simplexml`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) instead?

Comment: @Mr.Smith This is just one way I found to do it - if you can provide an example with simplexml and it works I would gladly use that.

Comment: just saw the link and this: this looks great ill try it <?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlfile);
print $xml->City->Street->Address->HouseColor;
?>

Comment: Yes this is the reason why it is called **Simple** XML :)

Comment: @Mr.Smith - im trying with simplexml - can you tell me what i'm doing wrong - you'll probably get what I'm trying to do...`echo $xml->channel->item[$startval + $counter]->wp:postmeta[22]->wp:meta_key;` I am trying to get the correct item to edit - which is why i'm using counters in a loop - but i'm getting an internal server error so obviously my syntax is off...definitely looks wrong - but im not sure what is right :)

Comment: @Mr.Smith - `$startval + $counter` could also just as easily be `0` and it would still have the same syntax errors - just not sure how to do this.

Comment: Can you post URL where you have this XML file? I will try.

Comment: @Mr.Smith - i am working locally - i will post the entire xml file to the question for you to copy and paste - basically I am trying to go to the first item that is an actual item - (the first item right after "cd_6_flat") and get the `wp:postmeta` chunk associated with `_price` so I can change the value,

Comment: @Mr.Smith - the file is too big for me to post - i can send it to you somehow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not post something relevant in you example XML. The document element contains namespace definitions (the `xmlns:*` attributes). The data you're looking for is in the namespace defined by the `xmlns:wp` attribute.

You can use Xpath to fetch the data in a much more easy and stable way.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
// create an XPath instance
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
// register a prefix for the wordpress export namespace
$xpath->registerNamespace('wp', 'http://wordpress.org/export/1.0/');

// fetch all rss item element nodes and iterate them
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//item') as $item) {
  // get the price meta data as a number
  var_dump(
    $xpath->evaluate(
      'number(.//wp:postmeta[wp:meta_key = "_price"]/wp:meta_value)',
      $item
    )
  );
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/188516

Output:

```
float(18)
```

Now if you want to edit something you need to fetch it as a node. If the Xpath expression is a location path it will always return a node list, much like getElementsByTagName(). You can check if the list contains a value, but I prefer to do the limitation in Xpath and just use foreach().

```
// inside the item loop
$priceNodes = $xpath->evaluate(
  './/wp:postmeta[wp:meta_key = "_price"][1]/wp:meta_value', $item
);
foreach ($priceNodes as $priceNode) {
  $newPrice = 42; 
  $priceNode->nodeValue = (int)$newPrice;
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/188529

Be careful with DOMNode::$nodeValue. Only set values that can not contain a `&`. PHP has a bug here. Otherwise use it to remove all children and append a new text node.

```
$priceNode->nodeValue = '';
$priceNode->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($newPrice));
```

Comment: this works great! im going to google it now but maybe you can save me some trouble and tell me how to replace the `wp:meta_value` with xpath?

Comment: Not exactly with Xpath. DOMXpath is part of ext/dom. You just use the dom functions. I added an example to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

So this should work:

```
$xml = file_get_contents('/var/www/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/dummy-data/nspro.xml');
$content = simplexml_load_string($xml);

echo $content->item->postmeta[22]->meta_key;
```

My output of your code in question is:

```
_price
```

Comment: i tried it as you said and im getting: `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: but I have a variable `$startval` that is the index for the item that i want to edit - because in my xml file there is more than one item - how do i get like - the 55th `item`?

Comment: i'm thinking `$content->item[$startval]->postmeta[22]->meta_key;` but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I don't know how your XML looks like. It looks different in your description as what you posted in your question...

Comment: yah it is slightly different - there is just more than one item - i just couldn't post it all in the question - basically after `$content` there should be an array (or some structure like it) of `item`'s

Comment: so instead of only having to worry about one item - i need to go to the 55th item or something like that - i have it stored in a variable called `$startval` - so it should only be a slight modification to your `echo` line.

Comment: Can you post your XML to pastebin.com for example?

Comment: I need to go past all of the items ending with the one that has the title `cd_6_flat` - the item after that is the first item that I want to edit the `postmeta` chunk for.

Comment: so output the 50th item's `meta_key` related to `_price` if you can.

Comment: this is close - i can at least focus on one item - but it doesnt output anything for `postmeta`: `echo $content->channel->item[0]->postmeta[0];` The script runs fine...but no output. `$content->channel->item[0]->asXML();` allows me to see all the info for the item at least - but still not sure how to reference `postmeta`

Comment: It only works if I deleted `<rss ...>` and `</rss>` but then is `Woo Logo` as `51` item ID: `$content->item[51]->postmeta[22]->meta_key`. See edited XML here:  http://pastebin.com/4PdBTEHk

Comment: I tried deleting rss and also just copying and pasting your pastebin and I'm getting a ton of errors now - the first one is `Warning: simplexml_load_string(): namespace error : Namespace prefix wp on wxr_version is not defined in /var/www/FBAInventoryServiceMWS/Samples/ListInventorySupplySample.php on line 230` - but there are too many for me to copy and paste - im assuming that something is now wrong syntactically that is throwing off the compiler on like every single line it seems like.

Comment: i actually think the rss is important somehow - it seems to have something to do with the `wp:` - `xmlns:wp="http://wordpress.org/export/1.2/"` as well as a few other things...